# Access SEMrush api response data

Tags: javascript, php, json

I am working with the SEMrush api and I'm having some trouble pulling data from their api's response as it doesn't follow a standard "key:value" JSON format. In the example below shows all of the keys and values are being displayed in their own rows.

Request Example:

```
http://api.semrush.com/?key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&type=domain_ranks&export_columns=Db,Dn,Rk,Or,Ot,Oc,Ad,At,Ac&domain=seobook.com&database=us
```

Response:

```
Database;Domain;Rank;Organic Keywords;Organic Traffic;Organic Cost;Adwords Keywords;Adwords Traffic;Adwords Cost
us;seobook.com;24041;5249;37332;143496;0;0;0
```

I've had minimal success using this method in JavaScript:

```
function get_sem(){
var results = document.getElementById("sem-test");
var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
hr.open("GET", "sem-test.php", true);
hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
    var data = JSON.parse(hr.responseText);
    results.innerHTML = data.rank;
  }
}

hr.send(null);
results.innerHTML = "Requesting...";
}

get_sem();
```

How can I accurately target these values?

Source:
http://www.semrush.com/api-analytics/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `SEMrush` response's format is really strange. How I implemented it in the one of my tasks with it. PHP side ( e.g. I needed `Organic Traffic`):

```
E.g. response is "Rank;Organic Keywords;Organic Traffic;Organic Cost;Adwords Keywords;Adwords Traffic;Adwords Cost 114787;2173;1400;338;37;1645;634"

// split names & values
list($names,$values) = preg_split("/[\s,][\d]/",$response);// <= set here your regex according your response 
$names = str_replace(' ','_',trim($names)); 
$names = explode(';',$names);
$values = explode(';',$values);
$SEMrush_data = array_combine($names,$values);   
echo $SEMrush_data['Organic_Traffic]; // 1400
var_dump($SEMrush_data);
// OUTPUT 
array(7) {
   ["Rank"]=>
   string(5) "14787"
   ["Organic_Keywords"]=>
   string(4) "2173"
   ["Organic_Traffic"]=>
   string(4) "1400"
   ["Organic_Cost"]=>
   string(3) "338"
   ["Adwords_Keywords"]=>
   string(2) "37"
   ["Adwords_Traffic"]=>
   string(4) "1645"
   ["Adwords_Cost"]=>
   string(3) "634"
}
```